# Asp.Net core MVC application Windows Authentication in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

My Asp.Net Core mvc web application requires Windows Authentication. In developpement, on IIS Express, everything works fine thanks to this setting

**launchSettings.json**

```
 "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:61545/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  }
```

When deploying to IIS, I get a blank page. The Request to my site get a 500 error code.

I tried to add this configuration to Startup.cs, as explained [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#application-configuration) , without success.

```
    services.Configure<IISOptions>(options => {
        options.ForwardWindowsAuthentication = true;
    });
```

When I look into the authentication parameters directly in IIS, Windows Authentication is activated.

I found some post talking about a package called `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener`, others about implementing a custom Middleware. I can't imagine this basic feature needs that much effort to work. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Are you sure the error occurs because of authentication? If so what is error message?

Comment: What is in your FREB log? https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: You can try fiddling with Application Pool Identities in the IIS Manager: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`launchSettings.json` file is only used by VS. When you publish your app (or run without VS) `launchSettings.json` is not being used. When you run with IIS/IISExpress you just need to make sure that your web.config has correct settings. In your case the `forwardWindowsAuthToken` attribute in the web.config is missing or is set to `false`. It must be set to `true` for Windows Authentication to work. A sample web.config before publishing would look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks for the info. You might need to create the web.config file manually if it doesn't exist, which happened to me using VS 2017, as described here: [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26751/publish-aspnet-core-to-iis-with-windows-authentica.html](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26751/publish-aspnet-core-to-iis-with-windows-authentica.html)

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to add the line

`services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`

in the method `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`

My app allows both Windows and Anonymous users.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x#windows-authentication-httpsys--iisintegration

Answer (score -1):

You need check web.config in your project dir. This settings was help me.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"/>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is invalid configuration in asp.net core 2.1