# Asp.net core Windows authentication only for specific users

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a web application protected by windows authentication. In Asp.NET 4.5 I can use the `web.config` file to specify exactly which users can use it

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="TEST\admin" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

In Asp.NET core the `web.config` file is gone, I guess the `allow` and `deny` rules should be moved to `launchSettings.json` file, but I can't find any reference on how to do it. So... How can I do it? This is the current authentication setting

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
}
```

Comment: You can use Thinktecture IdentityServer  and link it to your AD for instance

Comment: Did you work out how to do this in the end? Unfortunately, the answer as of Jul 2020 doesn't actually tell us how to add specific users, nor does the link provided. I would love to know if and how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually launchSettings.json file is only used by VS. When you publish your app (or run without VS) launchSettings.json is not being used. When you run with IIS/IISExpress you just need to make sure that your web.config has correct settings.

See this [Asp.Net core MVC application Windows Authentication in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084052/asp-net-core-mvc-application-windows-authentication-in-iis)