# Using Windows Authentication with Azure Service Fabric with ASP.NET Core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, azure-service-fabric

I want to use an ASP.NET Core Web API Service that should run in Azure Service Fabric. Is it possible to use Windows Authentication to secure the web Service?
I want to prevent that the user who uses this needs to log into the System manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only when using WebListener. Kestrel doesn't support it, because it is a cross platform implementation.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37746061/5946937) an example.