# MVC Core: Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-authentication

How can I get the DOMAIN/username in MVC Core once published?  I have Identity installed, and realize that for logged-in users

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

would work but prefer that all users do not need to be logged in.  Rather, I would like to use the client box domain/username.

In a local environment, I can do this with:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

but this doesn't work once published.  Once published it renders "IIS APPPOOL/AppName".  Is this the expected functionality?  If not, how do I fix this?

Most of the information I can find online relates to modifying the web.config file...

The closest I could find is [Windows Authentication with asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694211/windows-authentication-with-asp-net-core)

but I'm not sure how I would implement in the controller once I follow that

Comment: " I would like to use the box domain/username." Which box, the user's or the server's? You also don't need Identity for Windows authentication

Comment: the user's (client) machine.  And yes, I realize I don't need Identity for this function, but I use it for other functions within the application

Comment: `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` will give you the user's `DOMAIN\username` name when logged-in through Windows Authentication. It's not possible to get it without the user being logged-in, but, if you disable Anonymous Authentication, it *should be* automatic (though this would break Identity)

Comment: So adding this functionality and using Identity are mutually exclusive?

Comment: If you want auto-authenticate through Windows, I think so. Never really tried, though. For Identity to work you'd need `Anonymous Authentication` enabled, so `Windows Authentication` would not be automatic

Comment: are u hosting directly on iis or on some online hosting service?

Comment: I'm hosting on Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a decent amount of searching, it looks like it isn't easily feasible as Camilo Terevinto stated.  I'm going to have to implement Identity for all users.